# Phpmyadmin LIKE - ¿Que comunidades autonomas terminan en 'ANA'?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una tabla con las comunidades autónomas y las provincias de España, quiero encontrar aquellas comunidades autónomas que contengan al final 'ANA' (Comunidad Valenciana) esto es lo que he conseguido. He estado buscado soluciones pero no consigo encontrar una solución, AYUDA!!

```
select distinct autonomia from provincias where autonomia like 'ana';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si no me equivoco te falta añadir un % delante de 'ANA', quedando la consulta así, para que funcione correctamente.

```
select distinct autonomia from provincias where autonomia like '%ana';
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me ha funcionado correctamente. Buen dia!!